# Reload Angular 6 reactive form on back button click based on checkbox values checked initially

Tags: angular, checkbox, reload, angular-reactive-forms

In my reactive form, I am loading assets in checkboxes. When Submit button is clicked the values are passed on to a _dataService service class and retrieved on the next form 'forms' where it is routed to. The user could press back button from 'forms' and when this form reloads, it should be able to populate the initially checked values. I am able to retrieve the values back from the _dataService correctly in this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets, however, I can't figure out how to check the checkboxes. I guess how to set them to true or false. Here is complete sample code:

template:

```
<form [formGroup]="processDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" *ngIf="isFormReady">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">
                Select 
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-4" formArrayName='assets'
                 *ngFor="let option of processDetailsForm.controls.assets.controls; let i = index">
                <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" /> {{assets[i].option}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" id="btnNext" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="processDetailsForm.invalid">
                Next >
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reports',
    templateUrl: './reports.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reports.component.scss']
})
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {
    processDetailsForm: FormGroup;
    isFormReady: boolean = false;
    private selectedAssets;
    public dataProcessDetail;
    assets = [
        { id: 1, option: 'chk 1' },
        { id: 2, option: 'chk 2' },
        { id: 3, option: 'chk 3' },
        { id: 4, option: 'chk 4' },
        { id: 5, option: 'chk 5' },
        { id: 6, option: 'chk 6' }
    ]; 
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _dataService: DataService,
         private _router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.LoadControls();
        if (this._dataService.getBtnOption() === 'Back') {
            this.ReloadProcessDetails();
        }
        // this.LoadContactStreamsAssets();

    }
    submit() {
         this.selectedAssets = this.processDetailsForm.value.assets
            .map((v, i) => v ? this.assets[i] : null)
            .filter(v => v !== null);

        this.dataProcessDetail = {
            'selectedAssets': this.selectedAssets

        }
        this._dataService.setBtnOption('btnNextORBack', 'Next');

        this._dataService.setOptionProcessDetails('dataProcessDetail', this.dataProcessDetail);
        this._router.navigate(['forms']);
    }
    ReloadProcessDetails() {
        this.dataProcessDetail = this._dataService.getOptionProcessDetails();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets.length; i++) {
            this.processDetailsForm.controls['assets'].setValue(
                this.processDetailsForm.controls['assets'].value
                    .map(value => this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets[i].option)
            );
            }
    }
    LoadControls() {
        const controls = this.assets.map(c => new FormControl(true));
        this.processDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            assets: new FormArray(controls)
        });
        this.isFormReady = true;

    }
}
```

..and data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
    public btnData: string;
    public processData: any = null;

    setOptionProcessDetails(option, value) {
        this.processData = value;
    }
    getOptionProcessDetails() {
        return this.processData;
    }
    setBtnOption(option, value) {
        this.btnData = value;
    }
    getBtnOption() {
        return this.btnData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the value of the form in your service and then use `patchValue`.

```
submit() {
    this.selectedAssets = this.processDetailsForm.value;
    ...
}
ReloadProcessDetails() {
    this.dataProcessDetail = this._dataService.getOptionProcessDetails();
    this.processDetailsForm.patchValue(this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets);
}
```

[Here is a slightly modified version of your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyyvq7?file=src%2Fapp%2Freports.component.ts). save -> change checkboxes -> reload

Comment: I have edited post to complete example. Please guide

Comment: I updated the answer because the question is clearer now. But try to simplify the code next time.

Answer (score 0):

You patch the checkbox values using following method.

```
   ReloadProcessDetails() {
    this.dataProcessDetail = this._dataService.getOptionProcessDetails();
    this.processDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        assets:  this.formBuilder.array(this.assets.map(x => 
      this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets.indexOf(x.option) > -1))
    });
        }
```

Comment: Did not work! On initial form load all checkboxes are checked by default since I have FormControl(true), which I want, but when I go to next page and back to this form all get checkboxes get unchecked.